# How to keep HTML design only to the header and not the full page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am new to HTML so excuse me in advance. I cannot seem to figure out how to keep this current design to the top of my page (kind of like a header that follows you down the page). Right now, it takes over the entire page. I have a body of text below my Welcome to my Site header text but I cannot see it because it is hidden under this design, so I want to make this darkness + moving moon only the top 10% of my page. What it does currently is chop up the background multiple times, not leave the rest of it blank. Here is the code, TIA.

```
setTimeout(function(){
            $('.moon').css("animation-play-state", "paused");
}, 20000
```

```
@keyframes moon {
  0% {
    box-shadow: -150px 0px 0px 0px white;
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px white;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 150px 0px 0px 0px white;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}

html {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  background-image: linear-gradient(black 60%, #041931);
  height: 45%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
  background: none;

}

div {
  background: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

center{
  margin-bottom:-80px;
  margin-top:80px;

}

#text {
  color: #DAA520;
  z-index: -1;
}

.moon {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  animation: moon 20s linear infinite alternate;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset -10rem 0 whitesmoke;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    div {
        margin: 10%;
    }
</style>
        <h1 id="text"><center> Welcome to my Site! </center></h1>
        <div class="moon"></div>
        <div>Hi! In this site you will find information regarding the phases of the moon. Please look at the links attached below to gain a better understanding of items specific to the phases. </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works your html has a lot of issues and I would like to say try to use div's more as containers and style them.

```
<style>
  @keyframes moon {
    0% {
      box-shadow: -150px 0px 0px 0px white;
      transform: rotate(-10deg);
    }

    50% {
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px white;
    }

    100% {
      box-shadow: 150px 0px 0px 0px white;
      transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
  }

  body {
    font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
  }

  #text {
    color: #DAA520;
  }

  .moon {
    position: relative;
    width: 10rem;
    height: 10rem;
    background: #0a0a0a;
    margin: 1rem auto;
    animation: moon 20s linear infinite alternate;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset -10rem 0 whitesmoke;
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }

  .myheader {
    background: linear-gradient(black 20%, #041931);
    height: 40vh;
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
  }

  .mainBody {
    background-color: #DAA520;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="myHeader">
    <h1 id="text">
      <center> Welcome to my Site! </center>
    </h1>
    <div class="moon"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mainBody">Hi! In this site you will find information regarding the phases of the moon. Please look at the
    links attached
    below to gain a better understanding of items specific to the phases. </div>

</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('.moon').css("animation-play-state", "paused");
  }, 20000);
</script>
```

Comment: This almost works. It completely removes the dark background I had before and thus removes the animation.It also pushes the title below the moon and pushes it below too.

Comment: moon animation is working, is there any other animation?

Comment: Like the navy background completely disappears so you can't see the animation anymore. I wanted to keep the navy background with the moon animation but only have that at the top. It removes it from the entire page. And the title used to be slightly in front of the animation but with this, it shifts to the top